# Installed PyTorch with Anaconda, but cannot use PyTorch outside of the Anaconda Prompt

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, anaconda3

I installed PyTorch by running the following command in the Anaconda Prompt:

```
conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cpuonly -c pytorch
```

This command is given by the official PyTorch installation page. I then tested a short python script within the Anaconda prompt, and it worked. However, when I then open the Windows Command Prompt or a text editor like Atom, and run the same code that I did in the Anaconda prompt:

```
import torch
x = torch.rand(3,3)
print(x)
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'rand'
```

What confused me is that the "import torch" line isn't what causes the error, meaning Python is able to find some empty torch library to use. I've tried adding anaconda3 (where the PyTorch files are kept) to my PATH variable, but this changed nothing. I know I've installed PyTorch before using pip, but I uninstalled it, so this shouldn't be what's causing the problem.

So my question is: How can I fix this error so that I can use PyTorch outside of the Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Most likely the folder you're running the script from is named torch. Having said that, you need to know how to setup the environment properly with anaconda. It's not that difficult.

Comment: @OsmanMamun The folder I'm running the code in isn't named torch and I've never made a folder named torch. I'll look more into anaconda environments, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've had a lot of problems with Anaconda taking over as the "main" Python directory. Apparently this problem is wide spread (many programmers in a Discord channel I am in have the same problems). The answer lies in creating a virtual environment for Python and adding PyTorch it, adjusting your System Environment Variables so that Pip can install the PyTorch module in your chosen environment (whether for the default Python IDE or another IDE), or (and I had to do this) uninstall Anaconda completely and redownload PyTorch to your main Python IDE. The last option is the simplest because Anaconda overrides the Environment Variables and if you aren't going to strictly use Anaconda, it would be best to uninstall it to save confusion.